# How to get div X and Y (top left and bot right) , inside an image

Tags: image, html, resize, position

Here is what exactly I am trying to do.

I have an image with square elements inside it. When i click on top left and bottom right corners of those elements they are surrounded with divs with border. I then have functions to drag and resize those divs(once they are created by two clicks). I want to be able to record the resized coordinates of those divs in text boxes. For example if the image is with height=700 and width=500. Then if i create a square div inside it with coordinates top left(x=190,y=150) and bottom right(x=290,y=250). Then if i drag this div around the image i want those coordinates to change accordingly. Same thing to happen if i resize it.

Here i have added the code in a web site. laughter.free.bg/imagemapping/Img1.html What you need to do is click on top left and bottom right corners of one of the snack packs. Then you`ll see a box on the right with the coordinates of this Green bordered div. I want those coordinates to change when i drag or resize this div. You can see the code in the source of the page.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to bind functions to the resize event through jQuery.
For example, ur kiroid has a class of ui-resizable. You could use something like:

```
$('.ui-resizable').resize(function() {
    // refresh your coords here from $('kiroid').css maby?
})
```

Comment: Imagine i have and image and a div with a border inside it. That div has height=100 and width=100. And its top left x and y are x=50 and y=50 inside the image. But how do i get those x=50 and y=50?

Comment: the offset() methord will return the coordinates of an element relative to the document. to retrieve that "x=50 and y=50 in your case" you could calculate this difference

Comment: how can i get the offset relative to the image not the document?

Comment: var xDiff = $('your-image').offset().left - $('your-div').offset().left;  var yDiff = $('your-image').offset().top - $('your-image').offset().top;